# How would you create a high gloss finish on furniture?

Tags: finishing, sanding, paint

From a smooth lacquered finish like this:
[image: Nexera Platform Bed]

To a high gloss like this:

[image: IKEA Kitchen Cabinet]

How would I get create a finish like the picture above when starting with a smooth lacquer finished piece of furniture (i.e. IKEA Malm wooden furniture)? I know it is a multiple step process but I don't know what the best approach is. What tools/products would you need?

I'm a beginner to diy home improvement so any small tips/steps would be extremely helpful!

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this previous Question, [What is the best way to get a high gloss glass-like white finish?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-high-gloss-glass-like-white-finish) which itself was closed as a duplicate of [How do I achieve a “piano black” high gloss finish on wood?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/756/how-do-i-achieve-a-piano-black-high-gloss-finish-on-wood) These won't tell you how to do the effect in detail but give you a general outline of how it can be done. [contd]

Comment: Commercially this can be done using spray finishes of various kinds, all or most of which aren't available to Joe Public. You can get a similar level of finish with the right paint and/or overcoat, but it requires a lot of work and some practice to build up the right skills. Edges & corners present the most difficulty as it is very easy to sand through to primer or the wood/panel if you're not careful. making achieving a completely uniform gloss on something rectilinear with sharp edges extremely difficult. So don't underestimate the difficulty or effort involved if you want to embark on this.

Comment: Not to say that you shouldn't attempt it, just be prepared to put in a lot of practice time.