# Adding finish to a painted wooden table

Tags: finishing, furniture, finish-selection, tabletop, hardwood

So I have a table made and I was told that they applied a water based paint over it because I requested it to be black. The wood they used is either palochina or mahogany. As of right now, it isn't really rough (maybe like the texture of rubber?) but I can kinda feel the grain. I want it to be really smooth because I am using it as a computer table and really bothers me since my arms are on it more than 8 hours a day.

I have no experience in woodworking but since I had this made, I did get interested. In my research I found out that the easiest way I can add a finish on the table to make it smooth is to use a lacquer spray.

The issue I am having is that I am not really sure if I should add wood filler, primer or anything before I add more finish. I also found colored lacquer spray paint and I would prefer to use those since I would like to deepen the color that has already been painted on my table but I'm not really sure if it is the same thing as what is commonly used which is the clear one.

Hope someone could help me out on this or if you have any other suggestion besides lacquer.

Comment: You had a table made of mahogany ($$$) and _painted_ it? Kind of a waste of good, pretty, expensive wood. If you want it painted, use poplar - cheap, tight grain and takes paint really well. Consider stripping the paint and converting this to a table top. If not, it needs a good sanding to make it smooth, not wood filler.

Comment: check out [this](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/756/how-do-i-achieve-a-piano-black-high-gloss-finish-on-wood) for the ultimate black finish.

Comment: Spray lacquer is certainly **an** easy way to apply a smooth finish, but I don't know that you'll think it's easy once you try to do it on something the size of a table. You also have a potential issue in that you don't know if the current paint is compatible with your proposed clear lacquer, or coloured lacquer. [BTW "coloured lacquer" is a very vague term in the modern marketplace, it could even be applied to a product that any reasonable person would simply call *paint* ^_^] The only way to know for sure if they're going to be compatible is, unfortunately, to buy some and spray a test spot.

Comment: @FreeMan, I'm thinking with the mention of palochina that the mahogany could be Philippine mahogany, not the best example of woods sold under that name so we shouldn't be too upset by the thought of it being painting LOL